# Getting object with max date property from list of objects Java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I have a class called `Contact` that has a `Date lastUpdated;` variable.

I would like to pull the `Contact` out of a `List<Contact>` that has the max `lastUpdated` variable.

I know that this can be done by writing a custom comparator and using `Collections.max`, but I was wondering if there is a way this can be done in Java 8 that does not require using a custom comparator, since I just want to pull the one with a max date in just one spot in my code, and the `Contact` class should not always use the `lastUpdated` variable for comparing instances.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> and the Contact class should not always use the lastUpdated variable
>   for comparing instances

So you will have to provide a custom comparator whenever you want to compare multiple instances by their `lastUpdated` property, as it implies that this class is not comparable by default with this field.

```
Comparator<Contact> cmp = Comparator.comparing(Contact::getLastUpdated);
```

As you know you can either use `Collections.max` or the Stream API to get the max instance according to this field, but you can't avoid writing a custom comparator.

Comment: Is one or the other (`Collections.max` or `stream().max(Comparator<T>).get()`) more performant?

Comment: @AndrewMairose You can measure to see I don't expect much difference between both but only the measurements will tell you how exactly it is. The stream approach can however permits you to make the computations in parallel if your dataset is large enough to be worth it.

Answer (score 92):

Writing custom comparator in Java-8 is very simple. Use:

```
Comparator.comparing(c -> c.lastUpdated);
```

So if you have a `List<Contact> contacts`, you can use

```
Contact lastContact = Collections.max(contacts, Comparator.comparing(c -> c.lastUpdated));
```

Or, using method references:

```
Contact lastContact = Collections.max(contacts, Comparator.comparing(Contact::getLastUpdated));
```

Comment: Friendly reminder to future readers : Make sure you do a pre-check that the property is hydrated (not null).   In this case lastUpdated is not null for the items in the collection.

Comment: This throws a NoSuchElementException if the collection is empty

Answer (score 39):

Try the following (untested):

```
contacts.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Contact::getLastUpdated)).get()
```

Comment: This is working perfectly in my use case I had. Had to get the last one by getLastModified file which is a Timestamp in my case.

Comment: I always prefer this.

Answer (score 2):

Use `List<T>.stream().max(Comparator<T>).get()` after you defined a suitable `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you wanted to do it using java 8 lambdas, use this (assuming you have `List<Contact> contacts`):

```
Contact latest = contacts.stream()
     .sorted(Comparator.<Contact, Date>comparing(contact-> contact.getLastUpdated(), Comparator.reverseOrder()))
     .findFirst().get();
```

You can customize this comparator quite easily by simply appending further comparator. So the code is easily modifiable.

```
List<Contact> sortedContacts = contacts.stream()
         .sorted(Comparator.<Contact, Date>comparing(contact-> contact.getLastUpdated(), Comparator.reverseOrder())
               .thenComparing(contact -> contact.getAge()))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This does not work well with a large number of elements.
The sorted() method implies O(N log N) complexity and the approach that uses max(Comparator) (i.e., the accepted answer) has linear complexity which is better.

In other words, you do not need to sort the whole collection to find the single element with max property; only a single pass is required.