# Use Java 8 Stream API to filter objects based on an ID and Date

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Contact` class, for which each instance has a unique `contactId`.

```
public class Contact {
    private Long contactId;

    ... other variables, getters, setters, etc ...
}
```

And a `Log` class that details an `action` performed by a `Contact` on a certain `lastUpdated` date.

```
public class Log {
    private Contact contact;
    private Date lastUpdated;
    private String action;

    ... other variables, getters, setters, etc ...
}
```

Now, in my code I have a `List<Log>` that can contain multiple `Log` instances for a single `Contact`. I would like to filter the list to include only one `Log` instance for each `Contact`, based on the `lastUpdated` variable in the `Log` object. The resulting list should contain the newest `Log` instance for each `Contact`.

I could do this by creating a `Map<Contact, List<Log>>`, then looping through and getting the `Log` instance with max `lastUpdated` variable for each `Contact`, but this seems like it could be done much simpler with the Java 8 Stream API.

How would one accomplish this using the Java 8 Stream API?

Comment: It probably can, but how about this:  how would you do this *without* the Stream API?  How would you want to go about doing something like this?

Comment: How is this Question different than [the one you posted an hour earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31657036/642706)? Multiple good answers there showed you how to use steams to filter to get latest date.

Comment: @BasilBourque, the question earlier was how to get the object with a max date from a list. This question is more complex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can chain several collectors to get what you want:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

List<Log> list = ...
Map<Contact, Log> logs = list.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Log::getContact,
        collectingAndThen(maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Log::getLastUpdated)), Optional::get)));
```

Comment: This is close to what I was looking for, but I need the output as a `List<Log>`, not a `Map<Contact,Log>`.

Comment: @AndrewMairose, use `new ArrayList<>(logs.values())` after. Or probably simply `logs.values()` if `Collection<Log>` is fine for you.

Comment: Yup @TagirValeev that's what I ended up doing. I just tacked on a .values() at the end to do it all in one statement.