# How to get object from list with maximum date time object

Tags: java, arrays, datetime, max

Below is my code to find the contact object with the latest begin dateTime. DateTime is shown as an object.

Is there any method to simplify this code using streams and comparators.

```java
public ContactData getLatestContact(ContactData[] contacts) {
  int latestContact = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (DateTimeToolkit.compare(contacts[i].begin, contacts[latestContact].begin) > 0) {
      latestContact = i;
    }
  }
  return contacts[latestContact];
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting object with max date property from list of objects Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31657036/getting-object-with-max-date-property-from-list-of-objects-java-8)

Comment: @Hülya no because in my one there is no getter for date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that begin is a java.util.Date or any other Comparable? Then you could do:

```
public ContactData getLatestContact(ContactData[] contacts) {
    return Stream.of(contacts).sorted((a, b) -> DateTimeToolkit.compare(a.begin, b.begin)).findFirst().get();
}
```

Comment: Only way to compare date is DateTimeToolkit.compare.  java.util.Date is not used

Comment: OK, I updated the answer to use DateTimeToolkit.

Answer (score 4):

This should be done like this (assuming `ContactData` has a getter for `begin` field):

```java
public ContactData getLatestContact(ContactData ... contacts) {
    return Arrays.stream(contacts)
                 .max(Comparator.comparing(ContactData::getBegin))
                 .orElse(null);
}
```

**Update**
If there's no getter for `begin` field, the method reference should be replaced with a lambda `d -> d.begin`

```java
public ContactData getLatestContact(ContactData ... contacts) {
    return Arrays.stream(contacts)
                 .max(Comparator.comparing(d -> d.begin))
                 .orElse(null);
}
```

If it is *extremely* needed to use only `DateTimeToolkit::compare` to compare the date-time field, it may be done using another lambda `(d1, d2) -> DateTimeToolkit.compare(d1.begin, d2.begin)`:

```java
public ContactData getLatestContact(ContactData ... contacts) {
    return Arrays.stream(contacts)
                 .max((d1, d2) -> DateTimeToolkit.compare(d1.begin, d2.begin))
                 .orElse(null);
}
```

Test:

```java
System.out.println(getLatestContact(
    new ContactData("Jack", LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(7)),
    new ContactData("Jeff", LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(3)),
    new ContactData("John", LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1))
));
```

Output:

```
ContactData(name=John, begin=2021-02-18T11:52:51.014013200)
```

Comment: Theres no getter

Comment: then a lambda `d -> d.begin` can be used instead of the method reference, please check the update.  What is the type of `begin` field?